Complex conjugation can define the reals. What about vice versa?
This is another question about definability and the complex field. It is not as trivial as my previous question, here: Is $i$ definable from the complex field structure plus a predicate for the real numbers?. Let our structure be $(\mathbb{C};+,-,*,0,1)$. Consider the complex conjugation relation $C(x,y)$, which holds precisely when $y$ is the complex conjugate of $x$. The reals are definable by the formula $C(x,x)$. But can the reals define the complex conjugation relation? More precisely, in the structure $(\mathbb{C};+,-,*,0,1,R)$, where $R$ is a unary predicate that picks out the real numbers, is there a first-order formula $\phi$ in two free variables $x$ and $y$, such that $\phi(x,y)$ holds exactly when $y$ is the complex conjugate of $x$? I suspect it is not definable, but I don't think this question can be answered simply by automorphism considerations alone.

Where do you get $\Bbb C$ from, and can your definition and constructions derived from it equally apply to $\Bbb Z[i]$ or $\Bbb Q[i]$ or $\bar{\Bbb Q}[i]$? So what I am asking is if your question is circular, trivial and thus empty?

@LutzLehmann: The question isn’t circular or trivial, regardless of where $\mathbb{C}$ comes from.  It’s taking $\mathbb{C}$ (maybe constructed from pairs of reals in the usual way, maybe axiomatised as a black box, maybe constructed using a general algebraic closure) as the domain of a first-order structure with certain specified operations/predicates, and asking if a particular operation is definable in this structure.  The answers show it’s not awfully hard, but not quite trivial either.

Two complex numbers $x,y$ are complex conjugate when there is some complex number $j$ with $j^2=-1$ and real numbers $a,b$ with $x=a+j \cdot b$ and $y=a-j \cdot b$.
We don't care that $j$ is not unique.

Yes, if you have the power to check if numbers are real, then given some $x \in \Bbb{C}$ you can ask first of all "is $x$ real?", if so then return $x$, if not, then the complex conjugate of $x$ is the other root present in the unique monic quadratic with real coefficients that $x$ is a root of. We could for example implement this as:
$$C(x,y) \iff [(R(x)\wedge(x=y))\vee(\lnot R(x)\wedge(x \neq y)\wedge(\forall b\forall c((R(b)\wedge R(c))\rightarrow (x*x+b*x+c=0 \leftrightarrow y*y+b*y+c=0))))]$$
EDIT: I actually thought of a much more concise formula based on the same idea.
$$(R(x)\wedge(x=y))\vee(\lnot R(x)\wedge R(x+y)\wedge R(x*y))$$
If $x \in \Bbb{R}$ then $\bar{x}=x$. If $x \notin \Bbb{R}$ then since $[\Bbb{C}:\Bbb{R}]=2$ there is a unique monic real quadratic that $x$ solves. This quadratic is $f(z)=z^2-(x+\bar{x})z+(x\bar{x})$. The other root of this quadratic is $\bar{x}$. For a given $y \neq x$, the quadratic with both $x$ and $y$ as roots is $g(z)=z^2-(x+y)z+(xy)$. If $x+y$ and $xy$ are both real then by uniqueness of minimal polynomials $f=g$, and so $y=\bar{x}$. Conversely if $y=\bar{x}$ then $x+y$ and $xy$ are both real. (Note that since $x \notin \Bbb{R}$, $x+y \in \Bbb{R} \implies x \neq y$, so we needn't consider the case $x=y$).
It's actually possible to generalise this to detecting Galois conjugates in a field extension (by using the elementary symmetric polynomials).
[Or if you want a more direct computation not thinking about field theory so much: If $x$ is real its conjugate is $x$. If $x$ is not real then we can write $x=a+bi$, $y=c+di$ with $b \neq 0$. Then $x+y \in \Bbb{R}$ implies that $d=-b$, and $xy \in \Bbb{R}$ implies $ad+bc=0$. So $b(a-c)=0$, and then since $b \neq 0$ we get $a=c$. Now $y=a-bi=\bar{x}$.]

+1. Just a comment on syntax: In first-order logic, predicate symbols are not functions to ${0,1}$, so expressions like $R(x)=0$ are not well-formed. Instead, $R(x)$ on its own is an atomic formula with a truth value. So we write $\lnot R(x)$ instead of $R(x)=0$. I've edited your answer accordingly.

thanks for the ammendment

Fixed (based on comment below): There's also a simple quantifier-free way to do it: $C(x,y)$ is equivalent to $R(x+y) \wedge (\neg R(x) \wedge R((x-y)^2) \vee x = y)$.
This is now very similar to the solution given by Daniel Czmmx.
If $i$ can be used, the expression can be shortened to $R(x+y) \wedge R(i(x-y))$, but that was not allowed in the given question.
Added explanation: If $x = a+bi$ and $y = c+di$, then $R(x+y)$ implies that $(a+c)+(b+d)i$ has to be real, so $b+d = 0$. We then have $x = a+bi$ and $y=c-bi$. Then $(x-y)^2 = (a-c)^2-4b^2+4(a-c)bi$, so for that to be real, we must have $(a-c)b = 0$. So if $x$ is not real, then $b\neq 0$, and it follows that $a = c$; otherwise, if $x$ is real, we must have $x = y$.

Here’s another quantifier-free definition, aiming to be as conceptually clear as possible.  $\newcommand{\R}{\mathrm{R}}\newcommand{\Conj}{\mathrm{Conj}}\newcommand{\I}{\mathrm{I}}$  First note that a number is purely imaginary just if its square is real, but it isn’t real itself unless it’s 0:
$$ \I(z) \quad := \quad  \R(z^2) \wedge (\R(z) \to z = 0)$$
Now, two numbers are conjugate just if their sum is real and their difference is imaginary:
$$\begin{aligned}
\Conj(x,y) \quad := &\quad \R(x+y) \wedge \I(x-y) \\
  = &\quad \R(x+y) \wedge \R((x-y)^2) \wedge (\R(x-y) \to x-y = 0) \\
  \leftrightarrow & \quad \R(x+y) \wedge \R((x-y)^2) \wedge (\R(x-y) \to x=y)
\end{aligned}$$
This is quite similar to user67422’s answer, but perhaps shows more clearly where it comes from.
